# Sending an image to aws via php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, libcurl

The main problem that i've to do is sending an image from another server to AWS after some process. For that i've done the database processes in the first server. It works very well, i tested it. After that i've to send this image directly to AWS to start another .php file. I try it via cURL function:

server1.php the php file that's found in the first server:

```
$url = 'http://myawsurl.com/server/test.php';
$imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

$post_data = array(
    'tmp' => $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
    'type' => $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"],
    'name' => $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],
    'data' => $imageData
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
```

test.php the php file that's found in aws:

```
  if ($_POST["tmp"] && $_POST["name"] && $_POST["type"] && $_POST["data"]) { 
        $target_dir_requests = "/requests/";
        create_folder_if_not_exist(ABSPATH . $target_dir_requests);
        $dir_for_req_server = ABSPATH . $target_dir_requests . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $dir_for_req_server = base64_to_jpeg($_POST["data"],$dir_for_req_server);
    // After some requests that i've to do and i've done 
    } else {
    echo "data sending error";
    }
```

i tried something for todo but they did not work. Could you please help me for find a solution ? Thanks.

Comment: What is the "something for todo" that you tried? We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: editted, base64_to_jpeg is working, im using it in another php file.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the variable is true or not with the if($_POST[])

What you actually want is to check if the variable isset

Try this and see if you get any result:

```
if(isset($_POST['tmp'])){
   echo 'test';
}
```

Or

```
$tmp = isset($_POST['tmp']) ? trim($_POST['tmp']) : null;
if(!empty($tmp)){
   echo 'test';
}
```

The curl itself should be working

Comment: is it enough to check just tmp ?

Comment: No, that was just an example. You need to check them all ofcourse (if they are all needed for your code to work correctly)

Comment: still waiting for the response, functions take time, sorry for delay

Comment: it looks like okey, for now there is no problem.